# SQL Server 2008 and EF7 (RC1) - Cannot Skip() and Take()?

Tags: sql-server-2008, pagination, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am aware that SQL Server 2012 and above has a new OFFSET syntax for pagination, which Entity Framework 7 seems to translate my LINQ to.

This explains why I'm getting the error `Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.` because SQL Server 2008 doesn't recognize it.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995502/paging-with-entity-framework-7-and-sql-server-2008), someone answered that all we need to do, as of RC1 is to tack on `.UseRowNumberForPaging()` at Startup.cs's `ConfigureServices()`.

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
                    .AddSqlServer()
                    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => {
                        options.UseSqlServer("someConnectionString").UseRowNumberForPaging();                        
                    });
```

This doesn't seem to work. I am still getting the same error. My guess is EF7 still compiles my LINQ to the new 2012+ SQL syntax. What to do?

Comment: What is your query? It could be a bug in EF7.

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant, but anything db.OneOfMyEntities.Where(...)....Skip(x).Take(y).ToList() would produce this error.

Comment: EF7-rc1 has bugs in skip and take that are being worked on for RC2. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+skip+take

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SQL2012+ for use skip().take(), it doesn't work in sql2008.

For 2008 you can use:

```
select top 20 * from
(
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columnid) AS ROW_NUM
from tablename
) x
where ROW_NUM>10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be have been cross-posted and solved at [github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4616).

The solution to this problem is, as [stated](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4616#issuecomment-221331425) by Arthur Vickers, to go to your project's `Startup.cs` and add `UseRowNumberForPaging()` to your db's options builder.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
  options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(
      this.config.GetConnectionString("MyDatabaseConnectionString"),
      builder => builder.UseRowNumberForPaging()
    );
  }
);
```

I tested this with .NET Core 2 and it works fine.