# Skip() and Take() as Enumerable vs as Queryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I recently ran into an error while trying to use skip and take in a LINQ statement.

My statement looked like this.

```
DbConxtext.MyTable.Get(c => c.UserID == id)
    .OrderBy(orderProperty).Skip(index).Take(length).ToList();
```

Which gave me this error

> Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.\r\nInvalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement

I found out this is caused because OFFSET NEXT and FETCH did not work on sql server 2008, But I knew I was using paging in other places in my code and they all worked fine.

The difference between the ones that worked and this one was that **Skip** and **Take** were extensions of Enumerable on the ones that worked and Queryable on the ones that didnt.

So adding **AsEnumerable()** to the query fixed the issue for me. This seemed to generate SQL that uses **SELECT TOP(10)** instead of **OFFSET** and **FETCH**.

**EDIT:** *After reading over this again I realize that AsEnumerable will not generate different SQL. It will instead execute the query and do the Skip Take in memory.*

```
DbConxtext.MyTable.Get(c => c.UserID == id)
    .OrderBy(orderProperty).AsEnumerable().Skip(index).Take(length).ToList();
```

My question is what is the difference between using Skip and Take as extensions of Enumerable vs Queryable.

And why did EF decide to generate different SQL between the two cases.

Comment: `This seemed to generate SQL that uses SELECT TOP(10)` It will do no such thing.  You should look at the *actual* SQL generated to see the difference between the two queries.

Comment: The difference is that the `Skip` and `Take` will be applied in memory instead of in the DB.  Basically you're getting all the results and then filtering it down to the ones you want.

Comment: Skip() use for ignoring value like skip(2) this will ignore top 2 values. Take() use for fetching top values like take(2) this will fetch top 2 values.

Comment: Why do you believe that a select is generated when you use AsEnumerable? AsEnumerable means *stop generating SQL here*. I am interested to learn why people believe false things about programming; what led you to this belief?

Comment: @EricLippert I realize now that it is not correct, but I came to that conclusion after running that query in LINQPad 4, it has a feature that allows you to see the SQL generated from a statement and I saw that the query was using SELECT TOP. So I assumed that was the query it must be using when it doesnt give me an error. Completely forgetting that AsEnumerable will execute the query. :/

Comment: @Moe Your last sentence is technically wrong- which was Eric's point. `AsEnuerable` does not _execute_ the query - it just changes the context from building a query against the dataset to building a second query against the results of the first query.  Neither query is actually _executed_ until you try to iterate the results (via a `ForEach`, an aggregator such as `Sum`, or a transformer such as `ToList`).

Comment: @EricLippert My thought is that the abstraction hides the actual execution details (rightly so) from the programmer.  There's nothing obvious to tell someone _when_ the query actually gets executed.  Without reading the documentation, it's just as reasonable to assume that `AsEnumerable` executes the query as it is to assume that the query is executed at iteration-time. Unfortunately, most don't read documentation to this level of detail and just assume that `AsEnumerable` executes the query, since the context changes from SQL to objects with the addition of that statement and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the difference between using `Skip` and `Take` as extensions of `Enumerable` vs `Queryable`.

When you call `Skip` or `Take` on a type that implements `IQueryable`, the `Queryable` extension methods will be bound, and the underlying Linq provider (e.g. Linq-to-Entities) will process the `Skip` and/or `Take` and turn it into commands for the underlying data provider (e.g. SQL statements).  Whether the provider actually *supports* them or processes them *correctly* will not be known until run-time.

When you call them on a type that implements `IEnumerable` (but not `IQueryable`), the `Enumerable` extension methods will be bound, which just process the commands on the in-memory collection generated by the `Queryable` query.

> why did EF decide to generate different SQL between the two cases.

In your second case, the SQL query that is generated only incorporates the commands up until you inject `AsEnumerable()`.  That's all that the EF provider sees.  From then on, the commands will be bound to the `Enumerable` extension methods and will process the remaining commands in-memory.

> This seemed to generate SQL that uses SELECT TOP(10)

I highly doubt that.  What *should* happen is that the SQL query will return *all* records, but the in-memory iterator generated by `Take` will only return the first ten.

If you want the SKIP and TAKE to be processed correctly for a SQL 2008 database, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995502) for alternate solutions.

Comment: Note that .AsEnumerable().Skip().Take() is relatively efficient for small values of Skip() and SQL Server.  The client just has to Read() and ignore a few rows.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That's true for `Skip`, not `Take`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft But the entire set will be read into memory, correct? So if you take 10 out of 1M rows it will be much less efficient in-memory, no?

Comment: @Servy Take is the same in either case, those are loaded and saved in memory.  @D Stanley the first Skip+Take rows are read (and added to the ChangeTracker if enabled).  But the rest of the rows are not ever fetched from the database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Good to know. I always assumed the entire result set was loaded into memory.

Comment: Just tested this, and while the trailing rows are never materialized into objects, disposing the enumerator calls SqlDataReader.Dispose() will fetch the rows over the network from the server.  So it's actually not cheap.  Thinking about this, it's probably because the batch/proc could have additional commands that haven't run yet, and the only way to unblock the batch is to finish fetching the results.